# Error when placing tabular inside table environment

Tags: tables

I have a working tabular (maybe not that elegant) that I want to place within a table environment in order to get caption and to get it in List of Tables. However, this is not as simple as i thought. I've tried to make a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{TEST}
\label{tbl:testlabel}

\noindent \bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|l || c| c| c| c| c| c|}
    \cline{2-7}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & TRNSYS & Modelica & \parbox[t]{0.8cm}{Mat-Lab} &     EnergyPlus & \parbox[t]{0.7cm}{IES VE} & \parbox[t]{0.7cm}{IDA ICE} \\[15pt]
\hline
\hline
\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright{a\\b}} & N & N & N & Y & Y & Y \\[15pt]
\hline
\parbox[t]{4cm}{c\\d} & N & N & N & N & N & Y\\[15pt]
\hline
\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright{e\\f}} & N & N & N & N & Y & Y+\\[15pt]
\hline
\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright{f\\h}} & Y & Y & Y & N? & N? & Y\\[15pt]
\hline
    \parbox[c]{4cm}{\textbf{Number of "Y"}} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{4} &             \textbf{3} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{6}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I'm quite new to Latex, so I have no idea what is wrong. Share LaTex/Temaker tells me a } is missing on the second last line, but I don't get it!

Comment: remove `\noindent \bgroup`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten `\egroup` (matching `\bgroup`) between `\end{tabular}` and `\end{table}`.

Comment: while this is true, actually the extra group isn't needed inside the `table` environment, since that is a "closed" environment.

Comment: I know, but the question was substantially "Where is the missing `}`?", so I told him/her. Maybe he/she needs other `\arraystretch` values inside the `table`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! Thanks to @barbarabeeton aswell! :)

Comment: the presence of `\bgroup` before the `\arraystretch` would indicate that the stretch is to be limited in some way, and that makes good sense.  but the `table` environment makes this self-limiting.  (there may be another `tabular` further along in the document that now has a "missing" `\bgroup`, reported in the log as a `missing {`.  so @PhilN should check for that too.)

Comment: Maybe the `table` will contain two `tabular`s, @PhilN has not specified it.

Comment: If you just do this you will get a spurious space to the left of the table (from the newline after the `}` better to remove the `\noindent` (there is no indentation to suppress anyway as it is in the scope of `\centering`)